# Honeycomb Hardware Acceleration

Tags: android

I'm a little confused about the Honeycomb hardware acceleration. The documentation says to add a line to your manifest, but then it talks about hardware backing layers for views. If I simply add the manifest line, am I turning it on application-wide everywhere by default, or do I have to also turn it on for all the views in my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the attribute in the manifest, you will get hardware acceleration on every view. Each drawing operation (drawText, drawBitmap, etc.) will then be hardware accelerated. However, you can specify a View's layer type to cache that View into a hardware layer (an OpenGL texture.) Even with hardware acceleration on, some complex Views might take a long time to render, which may affect animations. By enabling a View's hardware layer you render the View only once (+ every time it changes of course.) For instance, if you do the following:

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 0.0f);
```

the view will fade out but its drawing code will be invoked only once.